# How to list all subdirectories in a directory

Tags: c#, directory

I'm working on a project and I need to list all subdirectories in a directory. For example, how could I list all the subdirectories in drive C:?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to get the subdirectories of the directory specified by *"your_directory_path"*. The result is an array of strings.

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("your_directory_path");
```

By default, that only returns subdirectories one level deep. There are options to return all recursively and to filter the results, [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx), and shown in Clive's answer.

---

**Avoiding an UnauthorizedAccessException**

It's easily possible that you'll get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` if you hit a directory to which you don't have access.

You may have to create your own method that handles the exception, like this:

```
public class CustomSearcher
{ 
    public static List<string> GetDirectories(string path, string searchPattern = "*",
        SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        if (searchOption == SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            return Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern).ToList();

        var directories = new List<string>(GetDirectories(path, searchPattern));

        for (var i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
            directories.AddRange(GetDirectories(directories[i], searchPattern));

        return directories;
    }

    private static List<string> GetDirectories(string path, string searchPattern)
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern).ToList();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var directories = CustomSearcher.GetDirectories("your_directory_path");
```

This traverses a directory and all its subdirectories recursively. If it hits a subdirectory that it cannot access, something that would've thrown an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, it catches the exception and just returns an empty list for that inaccessible directory. Then it continues on to the next subdirectory.

Answer (score 72):

It is as easy as this:

```
string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\My Sample Path\","*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Super solution!

Comment: The searchPattern as "*" was the secret, as we can't pass null, great solution!

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(fbd.SelectedPath);

foreach (string item2 in dirs)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item2);

    listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
}

foreach (string item in files)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);

    listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
}
```

Comment: if you want t do listing in a listbox and grant user to select which folder, yes, this answer works.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33255950/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TRIAL
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] fileArray = Directory.GetDirectories("YOUR PATH");
           for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
           }
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32754326/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).  For example, why `ReadLine()`?

Answer (score 2):

To just get the simple list of folders without full path, you can use:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(parentDirectory).Select(d => Path.GetRelativePath(parentDirectory, d)
```

Comment: Needs an extra closing bracket at the end (Would have edited it but need to change\add at least six characters for it to be accepted). Also note you need .NET Standard 2.1 installed to use Path.GetRelativePath

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best and fastest way to list all directories and subdirectories by skipping *System.UnauthorizedAccessException*:

A simple recursive method with an action to retrieve at realtime, preparing a list and returning to parent takes a lot of time. This callback function helps a lot to retrieve at realtime instead of preparing and returning back.

```
using System.IO;

private static void ListDirectories(string Path, Action<string> Listen){
    try
    {
        foreach(string Node in Directory.GetDirectories(Path)){
            Listen(Node);
            ListDirectories(Node, Listen);
        }
    } catch {}
}
```

#### Usage

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ListDirectories(@"C:\", (dir) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"retrieve at realtime"*?

Answer (score -3):

#### Show all directories and subdirectories

```
def dir():

    from glob import glob

    dir = []

    dir = glob("path")

def all_sub_dir(dir):
    {
        for item in dir:
            {
                b = "{}\*".format(item)
                dir += glob(b)
            }
            print(dir)
    }
```

Comment: This is Pyhon, not C#, isn't it?

Comment: This *seems* to be a ***totally bogus answer***, with a mix of [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). This will probably result in "`IndentationError: unexpected indent`". I have voted to delete this answer.