# How to get folders from physical path from server in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have deployed my web applciation in sever,  when i click a button folders from the "D:\Test\" has to be get added in the FolderName list

```
string path = @"D:\Test\";
List<string> FolderName = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in Server.MapPath(path))                
{
    FolderName.Add(s.Remove(0, path.Length));
}
```

but the above code doesn't work. in what way i can add folder name in the list

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296956/how-to-list-all-sub-directories-in-a-directory

Comment: Are you getting any error ?. If so, explain your error here.

Comment: @NicolasHenrard - Maybe a duplicate, but not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) expects an application relative path and will throw an error if given a physical path