# Get file names from folder and sub-folders in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I am trying to get name and location of all files from main folder and sub-folders and insert them in database, below is my current implementation and working fine but does not include those files that are in sub-folders, please help fix code below. thanks

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string VarDirectoryPath = "\\\\share\\folder\\";
            SqlConnection SQLConnection = new SqlConnection();
            SQLConnection.ConnectionString = SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "connectionString";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(VarDirectoryPath);
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCmd.Connection = SQLConnection;
            SQLConnection.Open();
            foreach (string filename in files)
            {

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);

                SqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert into dbo.FileInformation(";
                SqlCmd.CommandText += "[FolderPath],[FileName],[LastWriteTime],[CreateTime],[FileSizeinKB])";
                SqlCmd.CommandText += " Values('"
                                  + VarDirectoryPath + "','"
                                  + file.Name + "','"
                                  + file.LastWriteTime + "','"
                                 + file.CreationTime
                                 + "','" + file.Length / 1024
                                 + "')";
                SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            SQLConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A file system is a tree (or in some cases a directed graph). You will need to learn how to walk a tree using either recursion or a stack or queue and then apply that to the file system.

Comment: Please don't create SQL commands via string concatenation; use parameterized queries. You may be opening yourself up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Is that really an asp.net application? Why did you tag it that way?

Comment: This question might be useful: [how to list all sub directories in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7296956)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(VarDirectoryPath,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

for more details you can read [msdn-Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

Comment: Thank you Svyatoslav Ryumkin, worked perfect!