# How to get the names of a subfolder in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directory, path

I have a folder path with me something like "c:/videos". it contains subfolders like car, bike, bus ... etc. need to get only the sub folder name and store in a string array.

And please note i don't need a full sub folder path

out needed like:- car, bike, bus

not like c:/videos/car
c:/videos/bike
c:/videos/bus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to list all sub directories in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296956/how-to-list-all-sub-directories-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the SubDirectories.
And replace the startpath `c:\videos`with an empty string:

```cs
var rootDir = @"c:\videos";
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(rootDir);

var dirs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
foreach (var dir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    dirs.Add(dir.Name.Replace($"{rootDir}\\", ""));
}
var result = dirs.ToArray();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetDirectories method

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:/videos");
```

this will give you a string array of all the subdirectories and then you can call Path.GetDirectoryName() to get the folder name

```
 List<string> subfolders = List<string>();
 var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:/videos");
 foreach(var directory in directories)
 {
    subfolders.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(directory));
 }

 var result = subfolders.ToArray();
```

Comment: it is giving me the full path like  c:/videos/car

Answer (score 1):

```
string yourPath= @"C:\videos";

// Get all subdirectories

string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(root); 

foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)

    LoadSubDirs(subdirectory);


List<string> subfolders = List<string>();
private void LoadSubDirs(string dir)
{
  subfolders.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir));  

  string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

  foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)

  {

    LoadSubDirs(subdirectory);

  }

}
```