# Traverse a specified number of sub-directories with GetDirectories() C#

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have been looking through other pages but I cannot find a post that is similar to the problem I have been facing. I want to traverse through a certain number of subdirectories specified by the user but whenever I execute my code, it only ever gives me back one subdirectory even though there are more in there:

``

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);

DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = d.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo nextDirectory in subDirectories)
{                        
   if(depthCounter == 0)
   {
      break;
   } 

depthCounter--;
}
//User wants to go through 2 sub-directories so we decrement depthCounter until we reach 0. Then we break out of the loop and stop searching.
```

``

I heard that the default setting is to only grab one subDirectory, so if that is the case, is there any way to disable/change that setting? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to list all sub directories in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296956/how-to-list-all-sub-directories-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Charlieface I do not want to search all the directories, just 1 or 2 specified by the user.

Comment: If you take a look at the documentation for [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-6.0), you can see there is one overload that takes an argument of type [`EnumerationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-6.0). I think `RecurseSubdirectories` and `MaxRecursionDepth` in this object are what you're looking for.

Comment: @Jesse I did not see that, this looks like just what I need. Thank you both!

Comment: I didn't realize this before, but this overload does not seem to be available on .NET Framework. It is only available on .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET 5+.

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the post to show missing pieces (for all we know `depthCounter` set to zero  to start with and you just complaining that it does not meet your expectations of setting it to 1). Unfortunately @Jesse could not convert their comment to an answer since you requested ".net" (wich does not include Net 5+ where the depth option is available).